# SlidingDrawer rotation using onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, rotation, slidingdrawer

I found an Android bug that is giving me a lot of headaches.

Activity on Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityTest"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEST" />

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Big Big Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Now.. grab the handle of the drawer, and move it to middle and maintain the finger while rotating the device...

The **drawer dimentions get all screwed...** until it gets completely opened.

[image: Drawer in portrait closed]
[image: Drawer half opened in portrait]
[image: Drawer after rotation to landscape not resized (with finger still pressing)]

Someone has any ideia of how to fix it? I'm trying to look at the SlidingDrawer opening code to check why it gets ok when opened..but no luck yet.

Not handling rotation on my own is not an option that I'm willing to opt-in right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, managed to fix it with some tricks... the touch events sometimes don't get to the views after rotating with the Drawer half opened...

First I extended the Drawer and then: added some code to some methods:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    if (mTracking && !rotationStopTracking)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (rotationStopTracking)
    {
        rotationStopTracking = false;
         if (isMoving())
        {
            animateOpen();
            close();
        }else{
            animateOpen();
        }
    }

    ...

   }


//Called from Activity onConfigurationChanged
public void enableRotationResize()
{
    if (mTracking)
    {
        mTracking = false;
        rotationStopTracking = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with sliding drawers, so I'm just going to throw an idea out here and maybe it sticks to the wall.

What if whenever onConfiguration is called, you get the width of the scren and set the layout_width of the sliding drawer to that value? It *looks* like when you stop half way and rotate the screen, that the width (after the rotation), is the same as the width before the rotation. Maybe if you explicitly set the width, it will expand properly.